# Passing State in React-Navigation from TabsNavigation to Child StackNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**UPDATE: Now with a Snack Demo**

I've created a [demo on snack](https://snack.expo.io/@geirman/passing-state-in-react-navigation-from-tabsnavigation-to-child-stacknavigation) so you can see the issue first hand and help me demonstrate a solution in actual code.

Steps to duplicate

1. launch app
2. Tap "GO TO EVENTTABS" button
3. Tap each tab, noticing that the eventId is in scope for the first three tabs
4. Tap "More" tab
5. Tap "TEAM MEMBERS", noticing that eventId is no longer in scope. This is where the problem lies. How do I pass along eventId?

**_____________________________**

My App has the following navigation hierarchy, where every instance of `<>` is just a regular component

```
App <StackNavigator> {
    EventList <>
    EventTabs <BottomTabNavigator> {
        Quests <>
        Leaderboard <>
        Gallery <>
        More <StackNavigator> {
            MoreList <>
            TeamMembers <>
        }

    }
}
```

Upon entering the app, the user's first screen is `EventList`. They click a button to navigate into `EventTabs`, so I'm able to use the `navigation.navigate()` to transition while passing state like so...

```
EventList.navigation.navigate(EventTabs, passedParams);
```

To this point, everything makes sense. But `TeamMembers` also needs access to the `passedParams`. I'm confused how to pass those along. Hence my question...how do access `passedParams` from the `TeamMembers` component? They seem to be scoped just to the `EventTabs`.

If the answer is to use `navigate.setParams()`, then I'm not sure where I'd do that.

If the answer is to use `NavigationActions.setParams()`, then I'm also not sure where I'd do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't have good support for this, but you could use a function like this to recursively walk your navigation parents in search of the correct param.

```
function getParam(navigation, paramName) {
  const { getParam, dangerouslyGetParent } = navigation;
  let parent = dangerouslyGetParent();
  let val = getParam(paramName);
  while (val === undefined && parent && parent.getParam) {
    val = parent.getParam(paramName);
    parent = parent.dangerouslyGetParent();
  }
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks Eric! I've updated the snack demo to demonstrate the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to continue for version 5.x of react navigation. 
For me this works.

```
function getParentParam(navigation, paramName) {
    const { dangerouslyGetParent } = navigation;
    let paramValue = null;
    const parent = dangerouslyGetParent();
    const routes = parent.dangerouslyGetState().routes;
    routes.some((r) => {
        paramValue = r.params ? r.params[paramName] : null;
        return paramValue !== null;
    });
    return(paramValue);
}
```

You can iterate over parent.dangerouslyGetParent() according to the depth level you have